# C function returning incorrect data

Tags: c

I'm making a game using C and I have a function the reads a file and returns a pointer that holds the data for the level.

File: levelbuilder.c

```
bunker *read_rooms(char *rooms_file){
   FILE *bunker_file = fopen(rooms_file, "r");
   char room_name[MAX_ROOM_NAME_LEN];
   fscanf(bunker_file, "%s", room_name);
   bunker *result = create_bunker(room_name);
   fclose(bunker_file);
   return result;
}
```

Obviously right it doesn't do the whole level as I'm still testing things as I go. I'll list create_bunker below.

File: room.c

```
bunker *create_bunker(char *room_name){
   bunker *result = malloc(sizeof(bunker));
   result->room_name = room_name;
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++) {
       result->items[i] = NULL;
   }
   result->connected_to = NULL;
   result->next = NULL;
   return result;
}
```

This function works just fine.

When I check the variables in read_rooms using the debugger they all have the correct room name from file. However, in main the pointer to the level isn't NULL but it's room_name is. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You're storing a pointer to the local stack variable `room_name` after you return from `read_rooms`.  Accessing that after the function returns is Undefined Behavior.  You need to dynamically allocate memory for the new object's `room_name` field and copy it in.

Comment: What type is `result->room_name`? If it's a `char *`, then you're returning a pointer to an object that no longer exists since `room_name` (from `read_rooms`) is created on the stack and no longer exists when `read_rooms` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `room_name` is a local array in function `read_rooms`.

As such, it is pointing to a piece of memory on the stack.

The contents of that memory are valid only as long as you're "inside" the function.

Once you're "out", you can no longer rely on this piece of memory to contain valid data.

It might contain the data you'd expect, but it might not.

And even if it does, it may be overridden at a later point in the execution of the program.

So instead of setting `result->room_name = room_name`, you should copy the actual contents:

```
result->room_name = malloc(strlen(room_name)+1);
strcpy(result->room_name,room_name);
```

And of course, don't forget to `free(result->room_name)` before you `free(result)`...

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

result->room_name = room_name;

For

strcpy (result->room_name, room_name);

To copy the contents of room_name in result->room_name.  As you have it right now, you are making a char * pointer assigment and this is what will drive the program crazy.

Comment: This only works if `bunker.room_name` is a an array, what we don't know (yet?)!

Answer (score 0):

You allocate `room_name` on stack, than you pass ponter to it, and save to `result->room_name`. You can't rely on value that is saved on stack (created without malloc or something), it gets overwritten very soon when function execution is finished. Just use strcpy as Hernan Velasquez suggested

Answer (score 0):

For a start this line is wrong

```
 result->room_name = room_name;
```

As it will go out of scope and hence to the wolves. Perhaps make a copy.

I am sure there are other problems